# React. get state from another reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reducers, redux-reducers

**Hi how can i get the value from another reducer?**

```
const indexReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

switch (action.type) {

    case CALC_BET_AMOUNT:

        function calcBetAmount(value) {

            switch (value) {

                case 'max':
                    return userReducer.user_balance;

                default:
                    return state;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Return **userReducer.user_balance** - should return a value which is stored in another reducer

Its my **userReducer** code:

```
let initialState = {
    user_balance: 0
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not modifying state.  Reducers should modify state.  This looks more like a query on the state, you would want to use a selector for that.

Comment: I agree with this - the selector should be made available to the component.  If you're desperate to add it to another state, then you'll need to provide it through the action payload